# I am getting org.Hibernate.Exception.DateException: could not execute query. I don't know how exactly I should format the fromDate and toDate

Tags: hibernate

```
public ArrayList<IvInvoicePOJO> findByFromDateAndToDate(int maxResult,Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        formatter.format(fromDate);
        formatter.format(toDate);
        IvMasterDAO dao = new IvMasterDAO();
        ArrayList<IvMaster> invoiceList = null;
        ArrayList<IvInvoicePOJO> invoiceListPOJO = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder sqlquery=new StringBuilder();
            sqlquery.append("select ms.lc_netamt, ms.lc_total,ms.lc_vatamt,ms.usd_netamt,ms.usd_total,ms.usd_vatamt,ms.protocolnum,ms.docnum,cu.custname,cu.custvatid,cu.custlocid,com.countrycode,sr.spotdate,sr.currencycode,ms.employeeid,tc.doctaxcode,tcd.taxcddesc,ms.cdflag ");
            sqlquery.append("from iv_master ms, iv_customer cu, iv_companycode com, iv_users ur,iv_spot_rate sr, iv_tax_codes tc, iv_taxcode_desc tcd ");
            sqlquery.append("where ms.custaddrkey=cu.custaddrkey and com.companycode=ms.companycode and ms.employeeid= ur.employeeid and sr.spotdate=ms.spotdate ");
            sqlquery.append("and tc.doctaxcode=ms.doctaxcode and tc.taxcd=tcd.taxcd where sr.spotdate >= ' ");
            sqlquery.append(fromDate).append("' and sr.spotdate <= '"); 
            sqlquery.append(toDate);
            sqlquery.append("' order by ms.protocolnum");
            org.hibernate.Query query=dao.getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlquery.toString());
            query.setMaxResults(35000);
            List data=query.list();

            if (data != null) {

                invoiceListPOJO = formatToPOJO(data);

                return invoiceListPOJO;
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.error("Entity retrieval failed." + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                dao.getSession().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("connection failed to close");
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you add args to query. You have to do something like this:

```
...
sqlquery.append("and tc.doctaxcode=ms.doctaxcode and tc.taxcd=tcd.taxcd where sr.spotdate >= :dateFrom ");
sqlquery.append("and sr.spotdate <= :dateTo"); 
...
query.setParameter("dateFrom", dateFrom);
query.setParameter("dateTo", dateTo);
```

Comment: But the method setParameter(String, Date) is undefined for stringBuilder. What should I use for setting the parameters?
And the way I was using the query is working for other methods where we are fetching the results by passing String type, here when I am using date to get the all records from start date to end date. but unable to do so

Comment: Look carefully: setParameter is method in org.hibernate.Query class.